# PHP throwing error over static property that doesn't exist

Tags: php

I'm changing around some code in my project and PHP is throwing a very weird error about class property that no longer exists. The following is the error message:

> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$limit
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\Classes\model.php
>   Line: 48

And here's most of the method that's throwing the error, with line 48 marked:

```
$this->st->execute();
$this->st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($row = $this->st->fetch()) {
    return $max - $row->limit; // line 48
}

return $max;
```

`Config::$limit` used to exist, but I got rid of it when I made changes to the code. I've verified through a number of text editors that the code above is the real code saved in the PHP file, so it's not my text editor on the fritz.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What does `$this->st->fetch()` return? Does it have a public `limit` property?

Comment: is single equal sign a typo?

Comment: "limit" is a query field? I don't know what is Config::$limit, but your are getting an attribute (limit) from a fetch method.

Comment: @Amir the `=` sign is intentional.  `fetch()` can return false and you don't want to try to to treat `false` like an object (then you get fatal errors) so the assignment is wrapped in a conditional.  Maybe not the best style but a pretty common practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` seems to be an object of `StdClass` returned by `PDOStatement::fetch()`. Property names of this object correspond to the column names returned in your result set. If there's no `limit` property, that's because there's no `limit` column returned by your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

PDO::FETCH_OBJ means that each result row will be fetched as `stdClass` instance.

So the only possible reason is that `$row->limit` does not exist!
Add `!empty($row->limit)` check, try `var_dump()`it to make sure this is true.

Comment: D'oh, I was getting confused because I had a static class property with the same name which I was using before, I thought it was that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The error `Undefined property: stdClass::$limit` doesn't mean it's looking for a static property; that's just how PHP refers to properties in general (class::property).

PDO's `fetch()` will return either `false` if there is an error or some representation of the query result.  When you use

```
$this->st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

that tells PDO to return the resulting rows as objects of the default class `stdClass` with the column names of the row as properties.  So you're getting that error because the resulting row has no `limit` column.

You can `var_dump($row)` to investigate what is in fact being returned but most likely the query being executed is different from what you expected or it's doing a `SELECT *` and the database has changed the table definition.